# XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 while launching chrome dev tools

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I was trying to make modifications to the chrome developer tools and so I followed the steps listed here : https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/contributing
  and installed chrome build 155617 from [continuous builds archive](http://storage.googleapis.com/chromium-browser-continuous/index.html). And then I launch the chrome as follows :

```
chrome.exe --debug-devtools-frontend=C:\path\to\155617\devtools_frontend --remote-debugging-port=9222
```

When I try to inspect an element, I get the dev tools panel, however, none of the "Elements", "Resources" etc., panels are functional.
So to debug this, I inspect the devtools and I see the following errors in the console :

```
Uncaught Error: NETWORK_ERR: XMLHttpRequest Exception 101 utilities.js:855
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function Panel.js:314
```

Any idea how to fix this ?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you just do the dev environment setup or did you actually change any code?

Comment: I haven't changed any code, just set up the dev environment as instructed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've filed a bug https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=96211

Not all the required files were zipped into devtools_frontend.zip probably because we had switched to lazy loading schema. I'll try to fix it tomorrow.

The simplest way to fix that is to copy the content of WebKit/Source/WebCore/inspector/front-end from the repository into your unzipped version of devtools frontend.

You can get the current front-end from the repository with help of `svn checkout https://svn.webkit.org/repository/webkit/trunk/Source/WebCore/inspector/front-end` command